# How to dispose of a form within a panel upon closing the main form or upon another button click event?

Tags: vb.net

Disclaimer: I only have beginner to slightly intermediate experience with VB.net

Hello, I was tinkering around with some design ideas for a project and I ran into a problem that I haven't found a solution to. I have a win form with some buttons and a panel. When the user presses a button, a border-less form is loaded into the panel. The problem is this: when the main form is closed, Visual Studio does not stop debugging, presumably because the forms in the panel are not disposed of.

[Win Form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn9zu.png)

The instance of the panel form is declared in the button click event. How can I destroy that instance from another sub? If I click another button, the first panel form doesn't go away. Is there a better way to accomplish this? I'm still learning, so I'm often not aware of all the different ways to solve a problem. Thanks everyone!

```
Public Class frm_Clients 

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim search As New Search
        search.TopLevel = False
        search.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Panel1.Controls.Add(search)
        search.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frm_Clients_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        ' What should I write here?
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `a border-less form is loaded into the panel`  what purpose does that serve?  A panel is a container control, so the result is a super-container inside a container.

Comment: @Plutonix - good point, but what if I want to load many different controls, without them overlapping, depending on what button the used pressed? I don't want to clutter the designer and want to avoid hiding and showing a hundred different controls depending on which button was clicked. Do you have any suggestions for a smarter way to approach this? Thanks :)

Comment: a panel is a container control - it can hold many different controls.

Comment: @Plutonix - right, but as I said, the controls I want displayed in the panel depend on which button (outside of the panel) the user has clicked. I want different controls to be shown at different times.

Comment: What you should be using is a user control.  You add a user control to your project in much the same way as you add a form.  You then design the user control in much the same way as you do a form too.  The difference is then that you have a control, which can be used in the same way as any other control, instead of a form.  You can add instances of your user control to your form in the designer or in code, just as you would any other form.  In your case, get rid of the `Panel` and just add a user control instance. You can add them all at design time and then hide and show as required.

Comment: If you don't want to add all user controls at design time but rather create and destroy as required then you simply call `Dispose` on each control when you're done with it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - Many thanks! This is exactly what I wanted, I just didn't know about User Controls. Now I understand what Plutonix was saying.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of what to do to close the windows when another button is pressed.

```
    For Each form In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Form).ToList()
        form.Close()
    Next
```

Then I would suggest that you set search.Owner to the Form holding the Panel. That means that when the Owner is closed, so are the children.

```
search.Owner = Me
```